# Paytabs payment gateway Api not working

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paytabs

I am using the Paytabs payment gateway. Using the rest API Validate Secret Key providing all parameter but API returns every time in *"missing parameter merchant_email"* message.

```
 result = HTTParty.post("https://www.paytabs.com/apiv2/validate_secret_key",
   :body=>{merchant_email: params[:merchant_email],
           merchant_secretKey: params[:secret_key]}.to_json,
           :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
           'Accept' =>'application/json' } )    
          render :json => {:code=>345, :result => result}
```

Comment: Why this API give this message
{ parsed_response={"result"=>"missing merchant_email parameter", "response_code"=>"4001"}}

Comment: Api docs link : http://developers.paytabs.com/docs-apis/#rest-api

Comment: Because of this API support php language. I use this API on rails app through HTTParty method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve the issue through this process.

```
url = URI.parse('https://www.paytabs.com/apiv2/validate_secret_key')        
data = {        
        :merchant_email=> params[:merchant_email],
        :secret_key=> params[:secret_key]       
        }
    x = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, data)
    render :json => eval(x.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send parameters in header rather then the body?

Like this:

```
     headers = { 
        "key"  => "8781974720909019987" 
     }

     HTTParty.post(
         "https://www.acb.com/api/v2/market/LTC_BTC/",
          :headers => headers
      )
```

Comment: headers = { 
        "merchant_email"  => params[:merchant_email],
        "merchant_secretKey" => params[:secret_key]
      }

     result = HTTParty.post(
         "https://www.paytabs.com/apiv2/validate_secret_key",
          :headers => headers
      )
   render :json => {:code=>345, :result => result}
Like this?

Comment: Still the same message.

Comment: Same message also try this method Net::HTTP